# Android: getElementsByTagName equivalent?

Tags: android, reflection, view, getelementsbytagname

Is it possible to search the hierarchy of View and get Views of particular type?

Equivalently to `getElementsByTagName` in JS

defined like this:

```
public ArrayList<T> getElementsByTagName(View v, Class<T>){
    ....
}
```

called similar to this:

```
ArrayList<TextView> labels = getElementsByTagName(parentView, TextView.class);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) has `getChildCount()` and `getChildAt()` so you can traverse the tree and filter the children you want.